# DBLookuplistbox Column width

Tags: delphi

i currently have a DBLookupListBox with 2 ListFields, i was wondering whether it was possible to alter the widths of the display field columns or allow horizontal scrolling as one of the Listfields "Job ID" can fit easily with space to spare in the display field whereas "Job name" needs more space in the DBLookupListBox. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change [TField.DisplayWidth](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.DisplayWidth) (no of characters)